# Как при использовании Enzyme в тестировании реакт-компонентов вытащить содержимое тега?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jest, enzyme

Метод find() возвращает почему-то пустой объект {}. В доках и в примерах никто чистый find не использует, всегда find('tag').length(), почему? Ну и при следующем тесте ошибка из-за пустого received:

```
    const wrapper = mount(<Settings/>);
    expect(wrapper.find('h2')).toBe('Настройки')
```

При этом console.log(wrapper.debug()) выводит дерево.
Также тесты валятся из-за пустого received при попытке достать что-то из состояния компонента:

```
const wrapper = mount(<Settings/>);
wrapper.state('param').toEqual(somedata)
```

Ошибок в первой ситуации не возникает, если не использовать enzyme:

```
act(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Settings/>, container);
  });
  const label = container.querySelector('h2');
  expect(label.textContent).toBe('Настройки');
```

Но как без enzyme обратиться к состоянию компонента не ясно.
Как решить проблему с тем, что find и обращение к state через enzyme не работает или можно ли это как-то сделать без него?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашла два варианта:

```
expect(wrapper.find('h2').text()).toBe('Настройки')
expect(wrapper.contains(<h2>Настройки</h2>')).toBe(true)
```